# Ruby on rails 4.1.6 + Capistrano 3: purge gems on deployment server

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, bundler, capistrano3

Hy guys,
I have a server with apache, passenger 4.0.50, ruby 2.1.2 (started with 1.9.3), RVM and dozen of ruby on rails 4.1.x apps.

RVM is used only to manage ruby versions.

Follows the bundler configuration for each app:

> BUNDLE_FROZEN: '1'
>
> BUNDLE_PATH: "/PATH/TO/DEPLOYED/APP/shared/bundle"
>
> BUNDLE_WITHOUT: development:test
>
> BUNDLE_DISABLE_SHARED_GEMS: '1'

In order to save disk space (a lot of space) I would like to remove old gems of each application using **bundle clean**

The idea is to keep 2 releases (capistrano) and to run the command before a new deploy in order to keep gems for the last release.

The problem is that gems installed whit ruby 1.9.3 are not removed.

Can you please confirm that:

1. Gems for ruby 2.1.2 are installed in /PATH/TO/DEPLOYED/APP/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems
2. Gems for ruby 1.9.3 are installed in /PATH/TO/DEPLOYED/APP/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems
3. I can remove directory /PATH/TO/DEPLOYED/APP/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems since I'm not using ruby 1.9 anymore

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Mauro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont use ruby 1.9.x anymore, so just remove the gems directory for it.